# How to resize DataGrid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, resize, autoresize

Suppose that I've a DataGrid like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelDGV" runat="server" Height="100%" ScrollBars="None" Width="100%">
     <asp:GridView ID="DGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="30" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
            <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectCode" HeaderText="Project Code" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" />
     <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/Edit.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CommandName="CmdSearch" HeaderText="Edit">
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
     </asp:ButtonField>
             </Columns>
                <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
                   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                       </asp:GridView>
                          </asp:Panel>
```

Is there any way to resize the DataGrid to automatically fill the webpage like the Windows desktop picture feature? Like when I resize the page, the DataGrid is resized automatically. Thank you.

Comment: ever heard of Layouts ,they will do the job you want. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView` renders as an ordinary HTML table. So it should be style like it.

For example add a stlyle:

```
.mGrid
{
width:100%;
}
```

or `GridView` has a property which maps to html table `width`, which can be set to 100% too.